# About the BLoC class holding another BLoC class

Tags: flutter, bloc

I would like to have BLoC in BloC.
When using [Provider Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), it is the following code and it works correctly.

something_widget.dart

```
  home: MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      Provider(
        builder: (_) => LoadingBloc(),
        dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
      ),
      Provider(
        builder: (context) {
          var bloc = Provider.of<LoadingBloc>(context, listen: false);
          return SomethingBloc(SomethingRepository(),bloc);
        },
        dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
      ),
```

something_bloc.dart

```
class SomethingBloc {
  final SomethingRepository repository;
  final LoadingBloc loadingBloc;

  SomethingBloc(this.repository, this.loadingBloc) {
    fetch("flutter");
  }

  final _valueController = StreamController<SearchResultDto>();

  Stream<SearchResultDto> get value => _valueController.stream;

  void fetch(String freeWord) {
    loadingBloc.loading(true);
    var stream = repository.fetch(freeWord).whenComplete(() {
      loadingBloc.loading(false);
    }).asStream();
    _valueController.sink.addStream(stream);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _valueController.close();
  }
}
```

The question is what problems can arise if it have BLoC in the BLoC class.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of knowing possible problems if it is already working as expected. This question does not seem to be a technical problem to me.

If you have any specific doubts then add them in the question, Otherwise just taking a wild guess on the possibility of problems is not going to help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about whether or not a Bloc inside another Bloc would work correctly. If it's done carefully enough, it might work.

The real problem is the software architecture. Remember, it is always important to write code that is as clear as possible for other people. In your example, is not clear the dependency of one Bloc on another.

But before answering your question, there are a few errors in your code.

First, you are not following the Bloc pattern correctly. For that, I highly recommend you read the [official library](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/).

A basic Bloc should look like this (extracted from the official Bloc library):

```dart
/// The events which `CounterBloc` will react to.
abstract class CounterEvent {}

/// Notifies bloc to increment state.
class CounterIncrementPressed extends CounterEvent {}

/// A `CounterBloc` which handles converting `CounterEvent`s into `int`s.
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, int> {
  /// The initial state of the `CounterBloc` is 0.
  CounterBloc() : super(0) {
    /// When a `CounterIncrementPressed` event is added,
    /// the current `state` of the bloc is accessed via the `state` property
    /// and a new state is emitted via `emit`.
    on<CounterIncrementPressed>((event, emit) => emit(state + 1));
  }
}
```

Blocs listen to events and emit states in response. In the previous example, the CounterBloc's state is an `int`, which means that it emits integers (because it's a counter), but it can be a more complex data structure like another class.

Coming back to your example, you could create a `SomethingState` class that stores all the current state variables, like the current loading status (true or false), and emit those state changes when a user interacts with the UI, or when an asynchronous task finished, like a sign in request.

In the example you provide, I assume `LoadingBloc` would handle loading states. For that, a better approach would be to handle the loading status of SomethingBloc in its state (lets call it `SomethingState`), as I pointed out earlier.

The code would look like this:

```dart
/// Interface for SomethingBloc events
class SomethingEvent { }

/// Represents an asynchronous event (just for the sake of the example)
class SomeAsyncEvent extends SomethingEvent {}

/// SomethingBloc state class.
class SomethingState {   
   SomethingState({this.isLoading = false});

   // Here you should declare all the variables of your state.
   final bool isLoading;
}

class SomethingBloc extends Bloc<SomethingEvent, SomethingState> {
   SomethingBloc() : super(SomethingState()) {
      // Finally, when a SomeAsyncEvent is added, the loading status is set to `true` until the async method finishes.
      on<SomeAsyncEvent>((event, emit) {
         emit(SomethingState(isLoading: true));
         // << Call your async method >>

         // When the async method finishes, update loading status to `false`
         emit(SomethingState(isLoading: false));
      }
   }
   
}
```

Without more context, I cannot provide you with a more precise structure design for your code. But I highly recommend you to read the [official Bloc documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) where they explain not only [bloc package](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) but also [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) which makes it a lot easier to integrate Bloc with Flutter.